# arrays/lists of configuration settings c#

Tags: c#, configuration, settings

I have a winform app which contains some typical user settings. This form can be replicated depending on the setup at installation time, allowing the user to choose 1, 10, or 100 instances of this UI, which will all reside within the same main form. For a single/default setup there is one "set" of settings. What is the preferred way of handling multiple instances of these settings within the same application? Should I just go with standard properties and settings for each and use an app.config file, or is there a more suitable approach?

Thanks for any advice,

Gary

Answer (score 0):

I think create a form baseclass (e.g. FrmBase).This base form should contain a couple of properties that hold the user settings. You can let the baseclass load the standard settings on create.
 During the creation of the inherited form, you can adjust these standard settings.